# Как задать стили элементу дочерним элементам через класс?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    function textHighlight(str1, str2) {
        str1 = str1.text;
        str2 = str2.text;
      str1 = str1.split(" ");

      let str = str1.map(subStr => {
        if (str2.includes(subStr)) {
          return `<span onmouseout=\"this.style=''; \" onMouseOver=\"this.style = 'color:blue'\">${subStr}</span>`;
        } else {
          return subStr;
        }
      });
      return str.join(" ");
    }

var foundQuestion = findQuestion('"' + eachQuestion.textContent + '"'); // Возвращает вопрос в виде строки string
eachQuestion.innerHTML = textHighlight(eachQuestion,foundQuestion);  // Делает подсветку слов в eachQuestion
```

Однако в этом коде делается подсветка при наведении на каждое слово, а мне нужно так:

При наведении на блок, подсвечивались все встречаемые слова (а не каждое по отдельности)

Вабще я придумал вот что:
Присвоить класс всем нужным span элементам:

```
return `<span class="podsvetka">${subStr}</span>`;
```

Однако я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что мне нужно стили присваивать прямо в Javascript-коде
**То есть мне нужно выбрать из элемента eachQuestion все элементы с классом .podsvetka и установить им style="color:blue"**

Помогите

### UPD

1. Мне нужно повесить события onMouseOver и onMouseOut на eachQuestion
2. При наведении на блок eachQuestion менялись бы цвета у блоков с классом podsvetka (style='color:blue')

Comment: Вы знаете, что элементам на странице можно менять стили вот так: `element.style.color = 'red'` ?https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не туда копаете.

```css
.text:hover > span.podsvetka { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span class="podsvetka">Lorem</span> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum <span class="podsvetka">felis</span> eu pede mollis pretium.
</div>
```

Comment: У меня нету доступа к CSS
Менять нужно все на уровне Javascript

Comment: ...............

Comment: @z_index вы можете убращаться к любому элементу на странице с `class`, `id` и менять у него стили с помощью `element.style.nameStyle`

Comment: eachQuestion.innerHTML = "<span onmouseout=\"this.getElementsByClassName('podsvetka').style = ''\" onMouseOver=\"this.getElementsByClassName('podsvetka').style = 'color : green;';\";>" + eachQuestion.innerHTML + "</span>"; (я писал, мне нужно это, однако это не работает)

Comment: @z_index это работает так, как нужно, но вы не понимаете как это работает. Если вы опишите вопрос должным образом - что вам `нужно`, что вам делать `нельзя` в коде, то я могу написать ответ, как это делается на JavaScript

Comment: @МихаилКамахин 1. Мне нужно повесить событие onMouseOver и onMouseout на eachQuestion
2. При наведении на блок eachQuestion менялись бы цвета у блоков с классом podsvetka (style='color:blue') -- вот что мне нужно
У меня нет доступа к CSS.

Comment: @z_index это нужно обновить ваш вопрос `Вам`, чтобы всем было понятно. Исправить вопрос нужно так, чтобы 10-летний ребёнок понял, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Ок

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103136/discussion-between---and-z-index).

Comment: @fixeri
Если у меня в двух переменных содержится вопрос "Зачем нужен тег <head>", то в переменной eachQuestion стирается "<head>" (на форуме описал поподробнее)

Answer (score 1):

В `CSS` существует псевдокласс `:hover` , который определяет стиль элемента при наведении на него курсора мыши, но при этом элемент еще не активирован, иными словами кнопка мыши не нажата [Статья о **:hover**](http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.item {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 20px 1.5% 20px 0;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
 transition: border-radius .2s linear;
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 32%;
}

.item:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}

.item__title {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.description {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
}

.item__description {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 min-height: 81px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .3s linear,
    height .3s linear,
    transform .3s linear,
    width .3s linear;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 1px;
 height: 0;
 transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  font-size: 2vw;

}

.item__description__magic {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 10%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: black;
 transition: transform .2s linear;
}

.item img {
 transition: .5s filter ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover {
 border-radius: 20px;
}

.item:hover .item__description__magic {
 transform: scale(0);
}

.item:hover .item__description {
 width: 348px;
 transform: scale(1, 1);
 min-height: 81px;
 opacity: 1;
}

.item:hover img {
 filter: grayscale(100%);
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .item__description__magic {
    top: 18%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="item">
 <div class="item__title">Заголовок</div>
 <div class="description">
  <div class="item__description__magic"></div>
  <div class="item__description">
   Большоое Очеееень Описание
   Большоое Очеееень Описание
   Большоое Очеееень Описание
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="item__img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
 <div class="item__title">Заголовок</div>
 <div class="description">
  <div class="item__description__magic"></div>
  <div class="item__description">
   Большоое Очеееень Описание
   Большоое Очеееень Описание
   Большоое Очеееень Описание
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="item__img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
 <div class="item__title">Заголовок</div>
 <div class="description">
  <div class="item__description__magic"></div>
  <div class="item__description">
   Большоое Очеееень Описание
   Большоое Очеееень Описание
   Большоое Очеееень Описание
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="item__img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/250">
 </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Если хотите мучаться на JavaScript:

```js
function start() {

 let wrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
 let childik = document.querySelectorAll('.childik');

 for (let i = 0; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
  wrapper[i].style.cssText = `
   max-width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -moz-flex;
   display: -ms-flex;
   display: -o-flex;
   display: flex;
  `;
 }

 for (let i = 0; i < childik.length; i++) {
  childik[i].style.cssText = `
   flex: 1;
   min-height: 100px;
   margin-right: 1%;
   background-color: black;
   transition: .4s background-color ease-in-out,
      .4s flex ease-in-out;
  `;
 }

 childik[childik.length-1].style.marginRight = '0px';

 for (let i = 0; i < childik.length; i++) {
  childik[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   childik[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   childik[i].style.flex = '5';
  });

  childik[i].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
   childik[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black'
   childik[i].style.flex = '1';
  });
 }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', start);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="childik">
  
 </div>
 <div class="childik">
  
 </div>
 <div class="childik">
  
 </div>
 <div class="childik">
  
 </div>
 <div class="childik">
  
 </div>
 <div class="childik">
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня нет доступа к CSS